# automatically start voice recording like talking tom on this first word is missing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

in my code i am using 2 AVAudioRecorder one for monitoring the audio and another one for recording. In that recording is good but problem is the second recorder can't able to record the first 2 words or 2 sec. sample like this suppose i am say like "hi how are you" means it will record the "are you" words. http://purplelilgirl.tumblr.com/post/9377269385/making-that-talking-app with use of this tutorial only i wrote the recording functionality to my code. any one facing this same issue. let me know please regarding on this.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8rbm8awj9o4p4zz/TTGameMainController.m this is my code

Comment: You should include a sample of your code in the question, not as a link, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17177176/bold-a-specific-text-inside-a-contenteditable-div

Comment: Also, you should edit your question rather than posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep recording it all the time with low or high threshold, what you need to do is just, start playing from **time** when your `lowPassResults` exceeds to *0.5* in case *ajDanny's* example.

Comment: Now i am trying with one audio recorder. is it possible to play the sound with in the particular durations?. My sound has 1m 30s i need to play the last 50second. is it possible in simple audio engine in cocos2d